# Display a short version of long string on a div in React TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a React component that receives a long string and a numerical variable as props. The component's objective is to display a trimmed version of the string, based on the specified number variable. Additionally, it should include "show more" and "show less" buttons.

Despite attempting various approaches, none have proven successful. The original single-line string becomes multi-lined when placed within a div with defined width and height. My primary challenge arises when using the "useRef" hook to access textRef.current.innerHTML, which returns the original string without '\n' characters.

Do you have any suggestions on how to address this issue?

Comment: Could you share us your current progress e.g. in a codesandbox?

Comment: Need screen shots or sample code to address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are trying to achieve it, but this is a working example of a Read more and Read less that I have developed.
I hope it helps

```
"use client"
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react"
export function ReadMore({fullParagraph}: {fullParagraph: string}){
    const [text, setText] = useState<string>('');
    const [more, setmore] = useState<boolean>(true)
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(more){
            setText(fullParagraph.substring(0, 300))

        }else{
            setText(fullParagraph)
        }
    })
    const full = ()=>{
        setmore(false)
    }
    const less = ()=>{
        setmore(true)
    }
    return(
        <div className="">
            <p>
                {text} 
            {more?(
                <a className=" cursor-pointer" onClick={full}> Read More</a>
            ):(
                <a className=" cursor-pointer" onClick={less}> Read Less</a>
            )}

            </p>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Pretty clean and works great. Thanks! I mostly struggle with how to make the short version dynamic with a variable. In your example, the substring is of 300 lines In my case, it would be in various lengths and with the option the have small/medium or full version

Comment: Your welcome @OfirKariv If it is working please mark this answer

Comment: [Using `useEffect` here is recommended against in React docs](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state). You should compute `substring` during render instead to avoid having 2 render passes.

Comment: @AdamBasha I don't mark it since it is not the exact behavior I am looking for, thought it is pretty close :)

Answer (score 0):

Following @AdamBasha answer and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6iVByCOx8A), here's the solution. Note that the main css attribute, WebkitLineClamp, is being changed dynamically in the react code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./style.css"
export function ParagraphText({ text, lines }: { text: string; lines: number }) {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(true);
  const [textClass, setTextClass] = useState("show_trimmed_text");
  const dynamicStyle = {
    WebkitLineClamp: lines,
  };
  const handleShowButton = () => {
    if (showMore) {
      setShowMore(false);
      setTextClass("show_full_text");
    } else {
      setShowMore(true);
      setTextClass("show_trimmed_text");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={textClass} style={dynamicStyle}>
        {text}
      </div>
          {showMore ? (
            <div onClick={handleShowButton}>Show More </div>
          ) : (
            <div onClick={handleShowButton}>Show Less </div>
          )}

    </div>
  );
}
```

and

```
.show_trimmed_text {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.show_full_text {
    display: block;
}
```